# how to format bootstrap calendar value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I tried bootstrap calendar with multiple dates choose option.

http://jsfiddle.net/jdddpg3s/54/

```
$(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());

  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    todayHighlight: false,
    multidate: true

  });
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', today);
  activeWeek();
  $('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function() {
    $('#my_hidden_input').val($('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate'));
  });

  function activeWeek() {
    $('.day.active').closest('tr').find('.day').addClass('active');
  }
})
```

By choosing value will be displayed the text field. I can not achieve the following two points.

1. By default today date is adding to the input field.
2. I can not format the date values. I want multiple dates will be displayed like **13/12/2018 to 20/12/2018** while choosing the dates from 13/12/2018 to 20/12/2018 instead of the following format(13/12/2018,14/12/2018.....20/12/2018).

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit going on here so I created a verbose example to achieve the desired results (e.g. this code could be refactored but how it's achieving the results you want wouldn't be as clear).

To your first question on getting it to place the default value - which is the current date based on your use of the setDate method (`$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', today);`) - this isn't happening because you're invoking `setDate` *before* you define your `.on('changeDate')` event handler. By chaining the event handler definition to the initialization of the datepicker itself, this will populate the input field with the value at initial load.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    todayHighlight: false,
    multidate: true,
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
  }).on('changeDate', function() {
  ...
  )};
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', today);
```

In terms of the format & structure of the selected dates, that takes a bit more work. First, we can set the default date format to the format you want using the `format` option at initialization (see code above for implementation): https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format

Next, when multiple dates are selected, to display in the input field a string that is `EarliestSelectedDate to LatestSelectedDate` you'll need to first sort the array of selected dates, and re-sort it each time another selection is made. The code below, as part of your `.on('changeDate')` event handler does it this way:

1. On change, check if more than one date is selected; if so proceed, otherwise just display that formatted date in the input field.
2. If more than one, use the datepicker's `getDates` method to load your array with all the selected dates (https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#getdates)
3. Then sort the array from lowest (e.g. earliest) date to highest (e.g. latest) date.
4. Once sorted, grab the first item from the array (e.g. earliest date) and format as needed
5. Repeat but with the last item in the array (e.g. latest date)
6. Finally, concatenate the two dates as a string

Code:

```
.on('changeDate', function() {
    if($('#datepicker').datepicker('getDates').length > 1) {
        selectedDates = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDates');
        selectedDates.sort(function(a,b){
        return a - b;
        });
        var earliestDate = selectedDates[0];
        earliestDate = earliestDate.getDate() + "/" + (earliestDate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + earliestDate.getFullYear();
        var latestDate = selectedDates[selectedDates.length-1];
        latestDate = latestDate.getDate() + "/" + (latestDate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + latestDate.getFullYear();
        $('#my_hidden_input').val(earliestDate + " to " + latestDate);
    }
    else {
        $('#my_hidden_input').val($('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate'));
    }
});
```

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/21zd0fhL/

Refactoring you could include are things like a reusable function for date formatting (right now it's performed directly on the earliest & latest date), and checking whether or not each newly selected date is already in between the earliest & latest (in which case, you wouldn't need to reset the input field value). Unless users are selecting hundreds of dates though, you won't notice a performance impact to doing it on each `changeDate` event.